# Display root terms based on child in a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've a city vocabulary (see example below) which I import from 3-th party service. Each city may be spelled differently (either with wrong spelling or with special characters). In my example let's assume that TEST is a different variation of Oslo city.

[image]

These cities are already used in Content Type 'Person'. I built a view that display Persons with a category City. Everything works well and my view looks like this:
[image]

Now I need to substitute/replace TEST with Oslo (as it is different spelling of Oslo city).
On a view I expect to not see TEST and Oslo must get +1 as a counter.

> Oslo (34)

**UPDATE**
Here are my settings for the view.
[image]

What should I do in order to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

You can use relationship, and add "Taxonomy term: Parent term" field relation in it. Now make relationship with city field. It will give root term name based on child term name.

I have recently done this, it works.

Hope it will works for you.

Comment: I already have these relationship (look on 1-st image in question, TEST is sub for Oslo).
I can't figure out how to display parent instead of 'sub'.

Comment: I am asking to add relationship in views settings (look on 3rd image in question), there is no relationship defined in your views settings.

Comment: Could you please look on screen3 again (I've updated it). Is that what you mean? So far it does not work.

Comment: I did not get what was wrong first time, I've re-created relationship and it started to work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just watch it. Anyways, it helps you that's important.

Comment: I have an issue with that solution. It works only for child elements, in case if my Term is root - it will not see it and not show in the view.