# Get Root Term in a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

**WHAT I HAVE**

I've a vocabulary that looks like

```
France
- Paris
- Orlean
- Monreal
Spain
- Madrid
- Barselona
```

This vocabulary is used on my Content Type - **Product** via view (I've few similar vocabularies added the 1 view) in a field **Location** with type: 'Reference Entity'. Field may have only 1 value and it can be either Country or City.

**TASK**

I'm building a view where I would want to categorise my products by country depends on city/country (so I have to get Country in case if it is City).

```
France
 - product1
 - product2
 - ...
Spain
 - product1
 - product2
 - ...
```

I tried hard on a view but no success.

What should I do in order to only get Parent term if child is used on Content Type?

What kind of information can I provide to help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of [Display root terms based on child in a view](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175650/display-root-terms-based-on-child-in-a-view) - your older question? They sure look similar.

Comment: @Mołot : you are right, however for some reason the steps in the answer do not work for me. I must do something wrong and I can't figure out.
Is not it OK to create similar question? What should I do in such case?

Comment: Duplicating question because you don't like an answer is not good approach. Follow-up questions are OK, but they should show *clearly* what exactly are you doing now and where you got stuck. This one looks like "from the beginning" again, at least to me. If that's only me, it won't be closed or put on hold. If 4 other people thinks the same way i did (or one moderator), it will. So if you are afraid it's not only me, consider editing it to highlight differences and step you took, and make clear this time it's something different, narrower you are asking.

Comment: @Mołot I agree, you are right. I should not make new but follow up prev. one. Would it be OK if I delete question or you must close it as a duplicate?

Comment: Nobody answered, so you are allowed to change / focus meaning of this one. I'll be glad to retract my vote. Deleted questions are not good for your credibility. Edited ones don't - if anything, they show you want to improve and thus lessens the chance of bad things like question ban. Not that I'm afraid you may hit it, but better don't do *anything* in that direction ;)